# Inherited class from another module in Typescript

Tags: class, module, typescript, extends

I am trying to extend an abstract class to another class, but for more convenience I need to have this abstract class in another file. Unfortunately it throws me a runtime error which I struggle to understand.

This works :

```
abstract class Item{
   constructor(){
      console.log("I am an Item");
   }
}

export class Folder extends Item{
    constructor(){
         super();
    }
}
```

Log :

```
I am an Item
```

This doesn't :

```
module MyModule{
    export abstract class Item{
        constructor(){
            console.log("I am an Item");
        }
    }
}

export class Folder extends MyModule.Item{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Compiles but throws :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Does anyone understand what is going on ?

Comment: The problem seems to come from exporting an abstract class. A solution I just found would be to declare a var which would point this abstract class :

export var ItemClass = Item;

then :

export class Folder extends MyModule.ItemClass;

Does it look like a valid workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

A top-level export (`export class Folder` in this case) in a source file means that TypeScript will treat the file as an external module, though unless you specify the module format when compiling TypeScript should have emitted `error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.` So, I'm somewhat confused how you managed to compile those code snippets at all if you're only using internal modules.

I would strongly suggest using external modules (where each `.ts` file is a module in and of itself) and avoiding namespaces (previously known as internal modules) entirely.

Here's what your code would look like with nothing but external modules:

```
// mymodule.ts
export abstract class Item {
  constructor() {
    console.log("I am an Item");
  }
}

// folder.ts
import * as MyModule from './mymodule';

export class Folder extends MyModule.Item {
  constructor() {
    super();
}
```

However, if you wanted to stick to using namespaces instead, you'd do this:

```
namespace MyModule {
  export abstract class Item {
    constructor() {
      console.log("I am an Item");
    }
  }
}

namespace MyOtherModule {
  export class Folder extends MyModule.Item {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It works indeed, but is this a reasonable choice ? My ts project contains many files organized with internal modules.  Importing everything as an external module instead seems a crazy work. And according to http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript&referringTitle=TypeScript%20Documentation, "External modules are used in two cases: node.js and require.js. Applications not using node.js or require.js do not need to use external modules and can best be organized using the internal module concept outlined above.". 
What do you think ?

Comment: @Kromah That particular advice is dated, I believe the consensus these days is to use external modules with a module bundler (if you want to bundle everything into one or more files). However, I've expanded my answer to cover the namespace approach too. FYI TypeScript moved from CodePlex to Github some time ago, and that particular section of the docs can now be found in the [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook), which is also somewhat dated, there are a couple of pages on the Wiki that outline major changes of each TypeScript release.